# when waiting for response show reload icon using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, reload

I have this Typescript code, that get all data from backend.

```
getalleventsserial() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ns.eventsbyserial(params['id']).subscribe(
          notificcationserial => {
            this.notif = notificcationserial;
            this.isEmpty = (Array.isArray(this.notif)) ? true : false;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

and in this html code I can display data or only message.

```
<div style="text-align:center; color:#EE6E73;">
    <p *ngIf="isEmpty">Eventes for this product are: </p>
    <h5 *ngIf="!isEmpty">Events are empty!</h5>
  </div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <table *ngFor="let item of notif">
  <td>Date: {{item.dt}}</td>
  <td>Name: {{item.name}}</td>
  </table>
</div>
```

In this code I have a problem: When I get more data from service in display show this `<h5 *ngIf="!isEmpty">Events are empty!</h5>` for some time, and in the end data display in view. Have you any idea, how to solution this, or how to wait for data, in html display reload icon. When data arrive icon hide and show data, or show this message when response is empty? Like [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lydrmddoebm?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
// *.component.ts
...
this.isLoading = true;
this.ns.eventsbyserial(params['id']).subscribe(
      notificcationserial => {
        this.notif = notificcationserial;
        this.isEmpty = (Array.isArray(this.notif)) ? true : false;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );

//*.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">Loading... or your custom Loader</ng-container>
```

This can help you show both loader, error message(If present). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but I want to show in first Loading, not both. And in past show message , empty data or data. Thank you!

Comment: this will work as expected. 
1. Shows the loader.
2. After receiving the response from server, figure out is isEmpty should be true  or false. 
3. Hide the loader and either show the content of array or show `Events are empty` .